# xdg-open cannot find file which exists

Tags: command-line

I'm starting with WSL, and am encountering quite a funny problem. `xdg-open` can't find the index.html file which clearly exists! Really frustrating...would appreciate any solutions.

```
dist$ ls
index.html  main.js
dist$ xdg-open index.html
Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file
specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start "/mnt/d/work/web-development/webpack-demo/dist/index.html"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartP
   rocessCommand
```

[Screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjsV2.png)

Comment: xdg-open is basically a wrapper around some viewers used for display of various kinds of files.  An html file would get Chrome as the viewer -- is chrome (google-chrome?) installed?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. I was able to use `xdg-open` to open images, but not for a link. I found [this link](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewslutilities/+archive/ubuntu/wslu) by following an answer to [this issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/lgnx94/comment/gmsxkk5/). It suggests to update the system with unsupported packages by adding ppa:wslutilities/wslu to the system's Software Sources, using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wslutilities/wslu
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

It worked for me, though it changed the fonts of WSL after the use of `xdg-open` and changed back to normal after restart.

I thought this might be useful for someone else later. (I use Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @mook765! I edited my answer according to your comment. If there is anything else that I missed, please let me know! I wish you all the best! :)